# Изменение результата вызова функции rand()

Tags: c++

В программе встретил довольно интересный момент функции `rand()` и после него идут цифры.

```
mas[i] = rand() % 105 - 5;
```

Я понимаю, что это присвоение рандомного значения ячейке с индексом `i` в массиве `mas`

Тут интересует что под собой представляет вот эта запись `% 105 - 5`. Я так понимаю, что это число от `0` до рандомного максимума и остаток от деление на `105`, ну вот для чего еще `-5`. И зачем это использовать?

Comment: видимо нужны случайные числа от -5 до 100.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо поправил, и взял себе на заметку, то есть таким образом в С++, указывается насколько большой рандом, если указать %204-5; это будет от -5 до 204?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [`rand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) возвращает псевдослучайную величину в интервале `[0..RAND_MAX]`. Оператор `%` обеспечивает получение остатка при целочисленном делении. Т.о. запись `rand() % 105` будет давать значения из диапазона `[0..104]`. Вычитая `5` этот диапазон изменится на `[-5..99]`.

При этом Ваш вариант скорее сишный, чем плюсовый.
В современном C++ рекомендуется использовать функции, объявленные в заголовочном файле [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/).

Answer (score 0):

Такая запись предполагает, что в mas[i] будет записано число от -5 до 99 включительно.